# Need to write a function that receives a list of colours, and outputs their negative colours (pairs from a dict)

Tags: python, function, loops, dictionary

I've done this using list comprehension, but my code isn't satisfying by any means. How to make it shorter and more efficient? Note that I can't change the `cols` dict, and it'd be nice not to use any libraries.

```
def RevertCol(L):
    cols = {'white': 'black', 'red' : 'green', 'yellow': 'blue'}
    negative = []
    keys = cols.keys()
    values = cols.items()

    for col in L:
        if col in keys:
            negative.append(cols.get(col))
        else:
            for m, t in values:
                if t == col:
                    negative.append(m)
    return negative
```

**in:**

```
RevertCol(['red', 'white'])
```

**out:**

```
['green', 'black']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a copy of your dictionary and add the reverted entries. Then just use the list comprehension:

```
def RevertCol(L):
    cols = {'white': 'black', 'red' : 'green', 'yellow': 'blue'}
    cols_new = cols.copy()
    cols_new.update(dict([(value, key) for key, value in cols.items()]))
    return [cols_new.get(col) for col in L]
```

Comment: Your code seems to be the most laconic one while also keeping the non-changeable cols condition (though in a perfect world it'd not exist). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason to don't have all colors as keys on the dict? For example:

```
cols = {'white': 'black', 'red' : 'green', 'yellow': 'blue', 'black': 'white', 'green': 'red', 'blue': 'yellow'}
```

Then you could get the answer simply checking every color existence in the dict and returning the value.

If you don't want to expand the dict manually, you can programmatically do it:

```
inverse_dict = { v:k for (k,v) in cols.items() }
```

Also, you don't need to get cols.keys() in order to check if a key exist in the dict. Simply check with

```
if col in cols
```

This is more efficient because it is a hash table check (~O(1)) and not a list check (O(n)).

Adding this all up, you can have a solution like this:

```
def revert_color(colors):
    colors = {'white': 'black', 'red' : 'green', 'yellow': 'blue'}
    inverse_colors = { v:k for (k,v) in cols.items() }

    complete_inverse = {**colors, **inverse_colors}

    # If color exists in the dict, return the inverse, else return the color itself.
    return [ complete_inverse[color] if color in complete_inverse else color for color in colors ]
```

Comment: Your solution definitely works, it's just the university task that demanded not to change the cols. Anyway, I learned a lot from your code, thank you. I'll try to master your syntax, looks really great.

Answer (score 1):

To make your method both faster and easier to read, you can store all color negation in a single map

```
def RevertCol(L):
    cols = [('white', 'black'), ('red', 'green'), ('yellow', 'blue')]
    col_to_negative = {}
    col_to_negative.update(cols)
    col_to_negative.update((value, key) for key, value in cols)

    return [col_to_negative[col] for col in L]
```

You can also pre-compute `col_to_negative` once and then use it every call

Comment: Thanks, that works. Need some time to digest that return touch at the end, will take my time learning the syntax upcoming night.

Answer (score 0):

Invert the first dictionary, combine them, and then just grab what you need?

```
def RevertCol2(L):
    cols = {'white': 'black', 'red': 'green', 'yellow': 'blue'}
    cols.update({value: key for key, value in cols.items()})
    return [cols[i] for i in L if i in cols.keys()]
```

It reads clearer (to me) and eliminates those for loops.

Comment: That's quite elegant, I was thinking of this, though didn't have the knowledge. Now I do. Thanks.